# Laravel Backpack button that redirects to other Model's create view

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-7, laravel-backpack

So I have three models, Product, Sale and Code. Each Product belongs to a Code model (it's similar to a User) and each Sale has a field for the Code who is selling the Product and one for the Code who is buying it.
In the Product's list view I want to have a button called 'Sell' that redirects me to the Sale's create view with the Product's Code (basically the owner) passed in it so I can create a Sale with the Product and its Code already inserted.

I followed the documentation (https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.4/crud-buttons) for creating a custom button, but when I get to the part inside the new function (in the guide it's 'moderate', for me it's 'sell') I can't redirect to the create view of the Sale model (the one I get by clicking Create in the Sale's CRUD) created when I ran

```
php artisan backpack:crud Sale
```

How can I do this?

N.B.: I already built all the model's relative CRUDs.

Button's code: sell.blade.php

```
@if($crud->hasAccess('update'))
   <a href="{{ url($crud->route.'/'.$entry->getKey().'/sell') }} " class="btn btn-sm btn-link"><i class="las la-dollar-sign"></i>Vendi</a>
@endif
```

`sell` method in the `ProductCrudController`

```
public function sell($id) {
        // add redirect to Sale's create view with the product's id and owner 
    }
```

Sale model

```
class Sale extends Model {
    //
    use CrudTrait;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function code() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Code', 'code', 'code');
    }

    public function product() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Products');
    }
}
```

Product model

```
class Product extends Model {
    //
    use CrudTrait;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function productCode() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Code', 'code', 'code');
    }

    public function sales() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Sale');
    }
}
```

Code model

```
class Code extends Model {
    //
    use CrudTrait;

    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $primaryKey = 'code';
    protected $keyType = 'string';

    public function products() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Product', 'code', 'code');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the code for your custom button and the models showing the relationships?

Comment: Sure, I added it right now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *could* do the redirect in a method in the product's crud controller as you've started to, but I would actually do it directly in the button.

In `sell.blade.php` I'd do something like:

```
@if($crud->hasAccess('update'))
    <a href="{{ url('admin/sales/create/?code='.$entry->getKey() }} " class="btn btn-sm btn-link"><i class="las la-dollar-sign"></i>Vendi</a>
@endif
```

Note that assumes the path to your sale crud controller is `admin/sales/`, modify that if thats not the case.

Then, in your Sale crud controller where you set up your fields, set the field's default from the GET parameter if present something like:

```
    $this->crud->addField([
        'name'    => 'code',
        'label'   => 'Code',
        'type'    => 'text',
        'default' => request()->input('code', ''),
    ]);
```

Comment: Man, sorry for being late, but thank you so much! This was actually so much simpler than I thought! Thank you man